# Fullcalendar EvenDrop not have date "end"

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Hello look at this example, when I drop the event I don't have the END date and therefore when I click on it I miss this date bring in the edit form

[https://jsfiddle.net/max1974/msnyk1oL/1/](http://%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/max1974/msnyk1oL/1/)

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

  // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
  $(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
    revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
    revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
  });

});


/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
  drop: function() {
    $(this).remove();
  },
  eventReceive: function(event) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
  },
  eventClick: function (event) {    
    alert(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4))   
  }  
});
```

Comment: If an event has no end date you can calculate the end date by first checking whether it's all-day or not, and then using the value of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/defaultTimedEventDuration or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/defaultAllDayEventDuration as appropriate.

Comment: P.S. For future reference, your question can be closed as off-topic by the moderators if you don't include relevant information _within_ the question. A link to JSFiddle is not sufficient. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - item 1.